# Calculating probability of P(A|B,C), given probability of P(C|A,B), P(A) and P(B)

Tags: probability

Given:

```
P(A) = 0.6
P(B) = 0.1
P(C|A,B) = 0.2
P(C|A,Not(B)) = 0.4
P(C|Not(A),Not(B)) = 0.6
P(C|Not(A),B) = 0.8
```

Find P(A|B,C)

My Working:

```
P(B^C) = P(C|A,B)*P(A)*P(B) + P(C|Not(A),B)*P(Not(A))*P(B)=0.2*0.6*0.1+0.8*0.4*0.1=0.044
```

This is the part I am unsure about whether it is alright to do so:

```
P(B,C|A) = P(A^B^C)/P(A) = P(C|A,B)*P(A^B)/P(A) = P(C|A,B)*P(B) = 0.02

P(A|B,C) = P(B^C|A)P(A)/P(B^C) = 0.02*0.6/0.044 = 0.27
```

Is there any things that I am doing wrong here?
Particularly unsure about the part where

```
P(B,C|A) = P(A^B^C)/P(A)
```

Is it alright to also say that: `P(A|B,C) = P(A^B^C)/P(B^C)` ?

Comment: Yes, by definition $P(X\mid Y)=\frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}$.  This is true regardless of whether or not $X$ or $Y$ are themselves represented as single sets or as intersections of multiple sets.  So, replacing $X$ by $B\cap C$ and $Y$ by $A$ you have $P(B\cap C\mid A) = \frac{P((B\cap C)\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(A)}$

Comment: I think you should consider learning MathJAX (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it will make your formulas look so much nicer (also some times trying to write formulas with ascii will result in not getting the message through due to limitations of ascii).